# updating entities with hibernate if necessary

Tags: hibernate

i've got the following situation:
a user uploads a csv file. every line in the csv file is an entity. i parse the file and create thousands of enitities which i save in the DB via hibernate.
now it can be possible, that the user changes for example 3 entries on the csv file, but loads the whole file up. that means, for example 9.997 entries are equals and only 3 are different.
what's the best way via hibernate to update the data?

i hope that anybody can help me please.

thx very much in advance,
simon

Answer (score 1):

If you have a unique identifier and use `update` / `merge`, then hibernate won't create new records.

Comment: no, the problem is, that the UID (=primary key) is autocreated and when i parse the file the next time, i don't have the UID, so i need a way to find out, which entity in the DB belongs to a line in the csv file and then i have to check, if the values are equal or not.

Comment: so you cannot identify the records. Then you can't do it - delete everything and re-insert it.

Comment: i had the idea of saving the hashcode of every single entity in the DB too and after parsing the csv i can find every entity via the hashcode.

Comment: well, that's an option. Just make an index on the hash. And measure it, because it might be faster to drop & insert.

Comment: i think there was a problem, why i shouldn't drop and insert it, but i can't remember right now. :-)